# Should questions tagged with "technique" require knowledge in said instrument to answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

The top upvoted answer to the question, [Three notes on the violin?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45253/three-notes-on-the-violin) is actually in-correct. In fact, a lot of the ideas tossed around on this question are mis-informed. I of course mean no offense, and I deeply respect all of the people who make this site possible.

And obviously, these people are totally genius. You don't get tons of reputation on this site by faking it.

However, the question was about a specific technique on a specific instrument, and in some cases, as demonstrated, a knowledge of other instruments is not enough to answer questions about technique on other instruments.

So, on questions tagged as "technique," should users need some degree of expertise in that instrument to answer? Kind of like protected questions, but more specific.

Comment: I like this question, but as @Matthew Read says, there's no way to police it. Just yesterday I came across a very sophisticated question, but most answers were treating the OP as if they were a freshman struggling with a melody harmonization exercise (which was NOT the case). The best one can do is up/downvote and (when possible) provide an answer of your own. But it is frustrating when a less-than-ideal answer has 10+ votes!

Comment: That top voted answer is correct though. Even your comment agrees with it, and that's certainly the way we were taught to play things like that. Remember, sometimes you may be convinced an answer is wrong, but it may be correct. Just vote.

Comment: @DrMayhem Well, I don't want to start a discussion about whether or not the answer is correct, but I just want to say this. The answer is almost perfect as far a stack-exchanginess goes. It's well thought out and addresses the question head on. The thing is, that should not be played as an arpeggio. Almost all of the other answers say as much. But, yes, if anyone should know about being convinced about something incorrect, [it's me](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288868/what-do-i-do-if-the-information-on-the-main-website-isnt-true), so I respect the thrust of your comment.

Comment: Actually, General - when I read your comment and that answer, I thought they were almost the same thing. I think your question here is perfectly valid, though. It does happen, especially where someone is experienced in a slightly different field and mistakes the underlying context. The only exceptions to Matthew's answer on SE are the actual dangerous ones (Mechanics and DIY are two) where answers that pose a risk to life do have to be culled!

Comment: @DrMayhem Oh my word, I take it all back. Actually, the author of the question has specified and it turns out that, once again, I misunderstood the thrust of his question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Downvote and optionally leave a comment like you would with any other incorrect answer.  There is no sensible way for us to do that kind of policing, and there is no way to make an objective standard for subjective ideas like "how to play".  Downvotes and comments are sufficient to make it clear that something is wrong.

Comment: That sounds like a plan to me. The only reason I asked was because that answer is the highest voted answer to the question. To any random onlooker, it would look like the correct answer. Maybe this topic deserves its own attention (or a rephrasing -- like "How to deal with highly upvoted answers that are incorrect")?

Comment: @GeneralNuisance There has been a lot of discussion about that exact think on [Meta.SE], I'd check there.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say for the sake of the argument, that we do agree on that kind of policy: You can only answer technique questions on instruments you have some degree of expertise with. How are we going to verify that? Does the word of a user count? Do we need to see recordings and/or videos of their performance so as to judge their expertise? Do we ask for degrees/diplomas on the instrument?

I think even if wanted to do something like you suggested, it wouldn't be feasible in such a site. It's not a bad idea per se, and I can understand where it's coming from, but I doubt that it would be the best solution here.

Like others suggested, you can always leave a comment on the answer and specify that the answer is wrong and what is wrong with it, or even better you can leave your own answer.

Comment: Very thoughtful. Thank you for the advice.